# How can I change sudo error message from a file

Tags: sudo

I want to show text from a file.txt when I typed a wrong password.
I've tried:

**/etc/sudoers**

```
badpass_message=$(cat file.txt)

badpass_message=$(< file.txt)
```

But both was wrong. I got this error: syntax error.

Interesting it works with variables:

```
variable=$(cat file.txt)
echo $variable # prints content from file
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `sudoers` file is not a shell, so you cannot use shell constructs in it.

The [closest I know of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41058328/2344631) that you can get to, is to update `sudoers` (use `visudo`) each time you would have changed the contents of `file.txt`:

```
Default badpass_message="some custom error message"
```

As always when editing `sudoers`, (a) use `visudo`, and (b) have another root shell open (use `sudo -s`) while you are testing in the first window. DO NOT close the root shell window until you have confirmed that you have not broken the `sudoers` file.

You may find `sudo -k` useful while testing to reset the timer and to force re-entry of a password.